# mongodb query for the collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

What is the exact find query for the following collection

collection name : product

```js
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5e839abc4e"),
   "prod_id": NumberLong(9444529),
   "name" : "jonny",
   "pov_pack": null,
   "temp_id": "56kfhaksjd43" 
}
```

I tried the below query but it's showing me no records

```js
db.product.find({prod_id: "9444529"});
```

Comment: Try removing the quotes from the value so it's `db.product.find({prod_id: 9444529});`. Strings won't match numeric types.